# Spring Anotaciones no funcionan

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-tool-suite, annotation

Salvo por el Service, el resto de anotaciones no lo reconoce:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{    
    
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final RoleRepo roleRepo;

}
```

Comment: Si te encuentras trabajando desde IntellijIDEA realiza un invalidate caches o intenta modificar la estructura del proyecto estableciendo el uso de las dependencias maven asi mismo agregandolas a tu Pom.xml

Comment: Debes indicar si usas maven, gradle, etc para poder orientarte del como integrar las dependencias como lombok. saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, soy nuevo en esto, debo ser mas explícito con mis comentarios, estoy usando Maven.